# laravel job queue

Tags: laravel

У меня есть 1 job в laravel, я инициализирую его 10 раз через Job::dispatch(...).
Имея 10 воркеров, я все равно вижу, что исполняется одновременно только 1 job, в то время как 9 остальных стоят в очереди.
Как правильно сделать, чтобы каждый воркер взял по 1 job и начал синхронно их выполнять?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->dispatch((new TestOne())->onQueue('queue1'));
$this->dispatch((new TestTwo())->onQueue('queue2'));
...
```

потом

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=queue2,queue1
```

Взято [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599055/laravel-jobs-are-not-asynchronous)